# Bulletsharp Output?

Tags: c#, sharpdx

I am using Bulletsharp with a Sharpdx rendering engine.
I am trying to get the output from the world after I step the simulation

```
    public bool Frame(float timeStep, List<DModel> Models)
    {
        world.StepSimulation(1 / 60);
        foreach (DModel model in Models)
        {
            Matrix transform;

            Objs[model].GetWorldTransform(out transform);
        }

        return true;
    }
```

most people do `transform.Origin` but that just returns `0, 0, 0`

I'm trying to find the different positions that come out of the world